# How to handle React life cycle with http live streaming HLS?

Tags: reactjs, redux, rendering, http-live-streaming, hls.js

I'm using this [hls.js player](https://github.com/video-dev/hls.js) along with React to stream m3u8. I have one component `VideoPlayer` that sets up the hls.js player. This component has a couple of state properties, like `isPlaying` and `isMuted`. I have custom buttons that `onClick` call component functions to `setState`, but this of course re-renders the component and the video stream re-mounts I guess and is back to it's original state, which is back to it's first frame and stopped. In general, how do you deal with application (redux) or local state changes with streaming video? I notice the videos always have this "flicker" (which is it being re-rendered) any time the redux store updates, or local state changes.

**UPDATE WITH CODE EXAMPLE:**

```
import React, {PropTypes} from 'react';
import Hls from 'hls.js';

class VideoPlayer extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      isMuted: true,
      isPlaying: false,
      playerId : Date.now()
    };

    this.hls = null;
    this.playVideo = this.playVideo.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this._initPlayer();
  }

  componentDidUpdate() {
    this._initPlayer();
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    if(this.hls) {
      this.hls.destroy();
    }
  }

  playVideo() {
    let { video : $video } = this.refs;
    $video.play();

    this.setState({isPlaying: true});
  }

  _initPlayer () {
    if(this.hls) {
      this.hls.destroy();
    }

    let { url, autoplay, hlsConfig } = this.props;
    let { video : $video } = this.refs;
    let hls = new Hls(hlsConfig);

    hls.attachMedia($video);

    hls.on(Hls.Events.MEDIA_ATTACHED, () => {
      hls.loadSource(url);

      hls.on(Hls.Events.MANIFEST_PARSED, () => {
        if(autoplay) {
          $video.play();
        }
        else {
          $video.pause();
        }
      });
    });

    this.hls = hls;
  }

  render() {
    let { isMuted, isPlaying, playerId } = this.state;
    let { controls, width, height } = this.props;

    return (
      <div key={playerId}>
        {!isPlaying &&
          <span onClick={this.playVideo}></span>
        }
        <video ref="video"
          id={`react-hls-${playerId}`}
          controls={controls}
          width={width}
          height={height}
          muted={isMuted}
          playsinline>
        </video>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default VideoPlayer;
```

Comment: We cannot guess how you implement your component to help you. Please update more details.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is component's lifecycle.

playVideo -> setState -> componentUpdate -> componentDidUpdate -> initPlayer

So the player is initialized every time when user plays the video.

You can override "shouldComponentUpdate" so prevent update with no initializing the player.

---

Comment: You're right. `componentDidUpdate` should not even be used. I removed it completely and now the video does not re-initialize even when I change state within the component. I did not need to use `shouldComponentUpdate `.